# Keil doesn't see existing libraries

Tags: c, arm, keil

I'm trying to build a project in Keil, but when I have Cyrillic in file name, obviously I can't load a project to STM32 Discovery - it doesn't see my debugger! But the settings are right!
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6mT1.png) [pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etCHo.png)
but when I change a location to the other and run Keil "as an Admin", the Software doesn't see all the libraries at all!
[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nQiG.png)
Can you please help me to understand, what can be a problem here? I'm pretty new to Keil and trying to understand...

Thank you

Greetings,
Marina

Comment: Some software does not like non-US\b\bASCII characters or whitespace in path names, and µVision might be one of those.

Comment: These seem like two unrelated problems? What does the missing header got to do with the IDE not finding your ICD?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.